# Generating signed apk stucks when minifyEnabled true is used

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

While generating releases apk with minify enabled true ,gradle build doesn't finish and stucks at app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease.
[gradle build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjVEr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your build Types code with this code in app level gradle file. when you are debugging or running code on your device before final release then select built variant debug and when you are going to built signed apk for release then select built variant release

```
buildTypes {
                debug {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
                release {
                    shrinkResources true
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
}
```

Comment: when release signed  apk is made with minifyenable false its working fine, but not with true

Comment: @AadityaSawant did you found any solution?